# Aligning boxes twitter-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image]

http://pastebin.com/Ks1KL8Dr

Hello I'm using twitter-bootstrap and I'm having problem aligning the lower box with the upper one. Nevermind the strange box margins. Just temporary will fix them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle, that should help you: http://jsfiddle.net/5X6Gx/1/

Maybe you should also try http://www.jetstrap.com for building sites quickly with bootstrap.

Comment: Hey I found the solution. Thanks for taking your time to answer though. Jetstrap seems to be awesome.